# WPF Accessing dependency property from code

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a split pane which sits inside a dockmanager and it instructs the manager to let it be floating. from XAML i do this by

```
<Custom:XamDockManager>
    <igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
        <igDock:SplitPane igDock:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="FloatingOnly">
```

Now i have a requirement to do this dynamically construct the split pane from code. Question is, given an object, how do i set one of its dependency property at run time? The code sample given is using an infragistics dock manger control, but i think the concept will be generic wpf.

I tried the `dependencyObjectType.GetFields()` but did not find the dockmanager in the list for the split pane object.

From the code i am trying to

```
SplitPane childPane = new SplitPane();
xamDockManager.Panes.Add(childPane);
```

I am looking for something like *childPane.getDependency("xamDockManager").InitialLocation = FloatingOnly*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `SetValue()` method. In your case, this is probably how it's done:

```
childPane.SetValue(XamDockManager.InitialLocation, "FloatingOnly");
```